# How to create Windows XP styled fvwmrc file?

Tags: openbsd, fvwm

How to create Windows XP styled fvwmrc file?

Installed OpenBSD, it default uses FVWM2.

Does anyone has an rc file, that could make FVWM2 Windows XP styled? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one fvwm2 configuration that looks very much like Windows XP. So you do not have to actually create on your own from start.

[This page on xwinman.org](http://www.xwinman.org/fvwm.php) has noted the following:

> Here are some setups for version 2 of fvwm. They should either be called `.fvwm2rc` or `fvwmrc`, depending on how fvwm2 was configured [...]
>
> - From horen@mail.iucc.ac.il, added in November 2003: This screenshot (273k) shows fvwm2 configured to look very much like Windows XP. The configuration files (216k) for this are available, as are the numerous icons (3052k) [...]

*Note that links to the screenshot, configuration files and icons are intentionally not quoted here to respect bandwidth of the hosting site.*

The following screenshot is showing the setup:

[image: fvwm2-horen.jpg that is scaled down at 50% for fair use]

**Disclaimer**: I do not use FVWM and BSD systems. I just happened to find the resource from web search using the keywords "linux fvwm2 windows xp theme".

**TL;DR** Go to [the mentioned page on xwinman.org](http://www.xwinman.org/fvwm.php) and download the configuration file as Tar archive (gzip-compressed). The `fvwm2rc` and other configuration files are found inside the downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

http://fvwm-themes.sourceforge.net/

This FVWM theme compilation contains a plethora of themes, among which a *tribute* to Win XP style
[image]